# Dynamically registering controls in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

Can anyone tell me if I can dynamically set the file name when registering a user control please, for example:

```
<%@ Register src="[file name]" tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe you can. What you can do is register all of the possible controls that you might use on the page, either in the page directive or the web.config.

**EDIT**

What you can do, if this helps, is to add the controls dynamically in code-behind using the `LoadControl` method. This way, you can create instances of whatever user controls you want without worrying about registering them in the page directive or web.config. Thanks @Gabriel for pointing this out.

Comment: My instinct is that the OP wants the Controls.Add(new MyControl) functionality...?